# MySQL get mindate and maxdate in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

How to get the maxmum date and minimum date in mysql using only one sql query?

Comment: `SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date) FROM YourTable`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(date_col), MAX(date_col) FROM table_name
```

Comment: There is nothing that Icarus can do for the bug you are getting. His answer is correct regardless of the bug.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky hmmm I see. You either apply the workaround suggested or see if there's an update to MySQL that already addresses this bug, but my answer should work not only on MySQL but on most database products.

Comment: @Icarus Once again I ask first and then find out that I asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 22):

JUST IN CASE someone came here looking for minimum and maximum *supported* dates like I did... here's the answer to your question :)

```
select 
    DATE('1000-01-01') MinDate, 
    DATE('9999-12-31') MaxDate

+------------+------------+
| MinDate    | MaxDate    |
+------------+------------+
| 1000-01-01 | 9999-12-31 |
+------------+------------+
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: We are two peas in a pod here, thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 6):

Then do it like said [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54784):

```
SELECT MIN(CAST(date_col AS CHAR)), MAX(CAST(date_col AS CHAR)) FROM table_name
```

Comment: @aF... sorry, even though your answer is the one I'm using, Icarus's answer is more correct for my question.

Comment: @YuriKolovsky indeed, no problem :)

Comment: tusm, this fixed a bug that was plaguing me for hours

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Icarus's answer, but I prefer to rename the columns to something meaningful like:

```
SELECT MIN(date) AS start, MAX(date) AS finish FROM table
```