# Grouping table on the basis of date

Tags: mysql

I have the following table. I need to group by `fromdate`,
and get result with minimum `todate` for each `fromdate`. How can I do it?

```
|------|--------------|--------------|
|  id  |    fromdate  |     todate   | 
|------|--------------|--------------|
| 1    |  2016-03-01  |  2016-01-05  |  
| 2    |  2016-03-01  |  2016-01-11  |  
| 3    |  2016-03-01  |  2016-01-12  | 
| 4    |  2016-03-05  |  2016-01-05  | 
| 5    |  2016-03-05  |  2016-01-11  | 
| 6    |  2016-03-06  |  2016-01-04  | 
| 7    |  2016-03-06  |  2016-01-17  | 
| 8    |  2016-03-06  |  2016-01-19  | 
| 9    |  2016-03-09  |  2016-01-04  | 
|10    |  2016-03-09  |  2016-01-11  | 
|------|--------------|--------------|
```

I have tried this, but it is not giving me the expected result:

```
Select * from test group by fromdate order by fromdate, todate
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. And edit the question and add a [mcve].

Comment: Will you share any query you might have tried?

Comment: So why not do that !?!?!?

Comment: `** Select * from test group by fromdate order by fromdate,todate **`  -- want something like this.. which is not giving me proper result.

Comment: @NiyasNiya please accept the answer that you found most helpful. Click the hollow the tick next to the answer to accept it. Accepting gives you reps too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
SELECT fromDate, MIN(toDate) as minToDate FROM theTable GROUP BY fromDate
```

Comment: Oops! I was just 19 seconds after you!

Comment: thank you..
thats what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`min`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) aggregate function. The example given in MySQL docs looks somewhat similar to what you need.

```
mysql> SELECT student_name, MIN(test_score), MAX(test_score)
    ->        FROM student
    ->        GROUP BY student_name;
```

So, for your case it is going to be:

```
SELECT
    fromdate, MIN(todate)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY fromdate;
```

Take a look at the accepted answer of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727936/mysql-get-mindate-and-maxdate-in-one-query) that shows how to get minimum date, which of course uses `min()`.